# How do I generate JSON with ExpressJS/RailwayJS (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, express, pug, ejs, railway.js

I was exploring developing in Node.JS and found ExpressJS and RailwayJS (based on Express) which are frameworks for Node. The templating engine used Jade/EJS appears to be more for HTML. How might I generate JSON, eg. when I develop an API

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just create normal JavaScript objects, for example:

```
var x = {
    test: 1,
    embedded: {
        attr1: 'attr',
        attr2: false
    }
};
```

and

```
JSON.stringify(x);
```

turns it into JSON string. Note that `x` may contain functions which will be omitted. Also `JSON.stringify` returns `x.toJSON()` if `.toJSON()` is available.

Answer (score 56):

Express and Railway both extend off the HTTP module in node and both provide a "response" object as the second argument of the route/middleware handler's callback. This argument's name is usually shortened to `res` to save a few keystrokes.

To easily send an object as a JSON message, Express exposes the following method:

```
res.json({ some: "object literal" });
```

#### Examples:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({ some: "object literal" });
});

// -- OR -- //

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({ some: "object literal" });
});
```

Check out the docs at expressjs.com and the github source is well documented as well